# I cannot call my method Error must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

How i can call my method in upgrade() because it apears the error ' Error must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function'.

I want to have an Machine State, now i have the state monitor but i have a problem inside the upgrade() method.

```
template <class T>
  class StateMonitor {
  private:
    static const int MAXSTATES;
    static const int MAXLISTENERS;
    int internalState;
    int previousState;

    void* (T::*func_table[MAXSTATES_DEF][MAXSTATES_DEF])(int stFrom, int stTo);
    void* (T::*func_states[MAXSTATES_DEF])();
     
  public:
     
    StateMonitor();
    int addAction(int currentstate, void* (T::*handle)());
    void upgrade();
  
  };
```

```
template <class T> void  StateMonitor<T>::upgrade() {
  T::func_states[internalState]();
}
 template <class T> void StateMonitor<T>::addAction(int currentstate, void (T::*handle)()) { 
func_states[currentstate] = handle;
}
```

In a son class i call the method father, for example:

```
class Machine:public StateMonitor<Machine> {
private:
enum States {STATE_0=0,STATE_0=1};
public:
void* AccioSTATE_0(){/*some code to execute in current state*/};
void SetupGrafo(){
  addAction(STATE_0, AccioSTATE_0);
}
};
```

In the main loop, i want to create two objects of Machine class that have the same secuence:

```
Machine MachineA ;
void loop() {
  MachineA.upgrade(); //i want to execute the AccioSTATE_0
}
```

Comment: You have pointers to non-static member functions. You need an instance of `T` to call them on (just like you need an instance of `StateMonitor` to call `upgrade()` on).

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Comment: Show how `StateMonitor` is supposed to be used. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: `addAction(STATE_0, AccioSTATE_0)` wouldn't compile, you'd need `addAction(STATE_0, &Machine::AccioSTATE_0)`. The call in `upgrade` would looks something like this: `T* p = static_cast<T*>(this); (p->*T::func_states[internalState])();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when i compile `(p->*T::func_states[internalState])();` inside upgrade the compiler shows an error `invalid use of non-static data member 'StateMonitor<Machine>::func_states'
`

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/8cs418). The code you compile must be somehow different.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you, in the same file thats works fine, but if i put in the cpp file like this form?:                                                                                                         
 ` #include "StateMonitor.h"

template <class T> const int StateMonitor<T>::MAXSTATES = MAXSTATES_DEF;

 template <class T> void  StateMonitor<T>::upgrade() {
  T* p = static_cast<T*>(this);
  (p->*T::func_states[internalState])();
} ` it is correct?

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1670129)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i put `(p->*T::func_states[StateMonitor<T>::internalState])();` in the cpp file an i have the problem here. The header file of statemonitor.h ther i have correct. But i dont find the way to solve this problem

Comment: My code doesn't have `StateMonitor<T>::` before `internalState`. Yours does. In fact, `T::` is also redundant - make it `(p->*func_states[internalState])();`